# Angular EventEmitter with different types

Tags: angular

I’m building a checkbox component that can manage three states depending on if a prop is passed.

```
@Input() value: boolean|null = false;
@Input() triState = false;

@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<boolean|null>();
```

So when I want to manage a 3-state value it works, I pass in a variable of type `boolean|null` and no problem.

However, if I just want a normal two-state checkbox, I still have to pass in a variable of `boolean|null` type, which I find annoying for the client code. Passing a `boolean` value gives me the following error:

```
(For the value prop)
Type ‘boolean|null’ is not assignable to type ‘boolean’. Type ‘null’ is not assignable to type ‘boolean’.
```

I know that this is because my EventEmitter emits `boolean|null`. So what would be the best way to solve this? Is there a way to emit only a boolean if `triState` is false, and boolean or null if it’s true?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible options:

1. Using types for the EventEmitter generics:

   ```
   export type TriState = boolean | null;
   export type DualState = boolean;

   @Output() stateChange = new EventEmitter<DualState|TriState>();
   ```
2. Creating two separate event emitters:

   ```
   @Output() dualStateChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
   @Output() triStateChange = new EventEmitter<boolean|null>();
   ```

   - if `triState` is `true`, you would emit from `triStateChange`, else from `dualStateChange`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. First option seems perfect but doesn’t work for me - I still get the same error. Are you sure that it should work? Second one works but I don’t really like it since it has two values to bind to. What if I add an ngOnChanges that initializes the eventEmitter with either boolean or boolean|null, depending on the triState prop?

Comment: please replicate the issue you are facing in a stackblitz instance and share the link with us. We could help you faster this way.

Comment: even the primeng tristate checkbox uses an "any" for the event emitter: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/tristatecheckbox/tristatecheckbox.ts#L60

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I saw your comment when you posted it and have resorted to the "any" type for now. Thanks for your help